# Adding @bam.tech/react-native-batch to a fresh new react native project does not work

Tags: react-native

I try to `yarn add @bam.tech/react-native-batch` but I got the following error:

`node_modules/@bam.tech/react-native-batch/android/src/main/java/tech/bam/RNBatchPush/RNUtils.java:113: error: no suitable method found for put(String, batchEventData.put(key, URI.create(valueMap.getString("value")));`

and

`node_modules/@bam.tech/react-native-batch/android/src/main/java/tech/bam/RNBatchPush/RNBatchModule.java:529: error: no suitable method found for setAttribute(String, editor.setAttribute(key, URI.create(url));`

while doing yarn android (no error on iOS)

I am using *react 18* and **react-native 0.69.1*